# Multiple Dynamic Order By in Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

```
Dim receipts As IQueryable(Of ReceiptEntity) = db.Receipts

'code to filter removed for brevity

Dim sorts() As String = SortExpression.Split(";")

For Each sort As String In sorts
    Dim sortParts() As String = sort.Split(" ")
    If sortParts(1).ToLower = "true" Then
        receipts = receipts.OrderBy(Of ReceiptEntity)(sortParts(0).ToString(), SortDirection.Ascending)
    Else
        receipts = receipts.OrderBy(Of ReceiptEntity)(sortParts(0).ToString(), SortDirection.Descending)
    End If
Next
```

SortExpression comes in like "field1 true;field2 false;field3 true"

What I want to happen is for the query to have multiple order by fields, what is happening is that only the last order by is applied.  What am I doing wrong here?

---

Here is what the working result looks like:

```
Dim receipts As IOrderedQueryable(Of ReceiptEntity) = db.Receipts.Include(Function(r) r.LineItems).Include(Function(r) r.Payments)

Dim sorts() As String = SortExpression.Split(";")
Dim sortParts() As String
sortParts = sorts(0).Split(" ")
If sortParts(1).ToLower = "true" Then
    receipts = receipts.OrderBy(sortParts(0).ToString())
Else
    receipts = receipts.OrderByDescending(sortParts(0).ToString())
End If


For Each sort As String In sorts.Skip(1)
    sortParts = sort.Split(" ")
    If sortParts(1).ToLower = "true" Then
        receipts = receipts.ThenBy(sortParts(0).ToString())
    Else
        receipts = receipts.ThenByDescending(sortParts(0).ToString())
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ThenBy` instead of `OrderBy` for the second and all subsequent sort operations.

Comment: Thanks, you also have to use IOrderedQueryable(of T) instead of IQueryable(of T) in the declaration in order to get the ThenBy and ThenByDescending.